# Comment box without PHP & MySQL

Tags: xml, csv

Is there a way to create a comment box without PHP & MySQL?

My server doesn't support PHP & MySQL and I need to find a way to do a comment box system without them.

I found that this can be done with XML but I can't use that too.

Another way I found is to parse the data from a CSV, but I wonder if I can update the CSV file too, when someone writes a new comment. Is that possible in JavaScript or jQuery?

I did some research regarding CSV files but I couldn't find anything relevant. Ideally, but not sure if possible, I would write the comments and their details on an online CSV file and then parse them to my page.

What are possibilities are to create the comment box without PHP & MySQL?

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want it with php then why tag it with php?

Comment: what kind of server is this that doesn't support mysql and php ? , haven't you installed it?. There are many free hostings as well which you can use and also provide nearly all features for php and mysql apps.

Comment: do file saving without a server side language, can you even do that?

Comment: Are there any possibilities without PHP & MySQL? I know that there are free hostings with PHP & MySQL but I don't want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd side comment box apps, like https://www.htmlcommentbox.com/ . Does that fit well with your project? (Haven't tried this one out, it was just first link that popped out on google, however in past, I used something similar when I wasn't allowed to use PHP.)

You also (if you're permitted to) can create and read+rewrite a .txt file on your server.
[Javascript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)